# NUnit's closest equivalent of MbUnit's [DynamicTestFactory] for dynamic tests

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, mbunit, gallio

I'm looking for NUnit's closest equivalent to MbUnit's [DynamicTestFactory] so I can create dynamtic tests on runtime. Is there an equivalent in NUnit? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used MbUnit, but the closest thing to `DynamicTestFactory` that I know of in NUnit is `TestCaseSource`.

I found this example of `DynamicTestFactory` (from [here](http://www.skimedic.com/blog/post/2008/12/20/my-favorite-mbunit-attributes.aspx)):

```
[DynamicTestFactory]
public IEnumerable<Test> Should_Create_And_Execute_Dynamic_Tests()
{
   IEnumerable<int> list = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   foreach (int i in list) 
   { 
      yield return new TestCase(string.Format("Test {0}",i), 
         () => { Assert.IsTrue(MyFunction(i)); });
   }
}
```

This is how you would use NUnit's `TestCaseSource` (see [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.6.3)) to accomplish the same thing:

```
    [Test, TestCaseSource("SourceList")]
    public void MyFunctionTest(int i)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(MyFunction(i));
    }

    private static readonly IEnumerable<int> SourceList = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```